# Can ArcMap 10.2.2 Publish To Server 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

I realize you probably can't but I just want to verify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per this](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/compatibility-of-arcgis-for-server-with-earlier-versions.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F33189E0BB2746F3B84FA83A0B8119E0)

**Can I publish a service to 10.3.1 using an earlier version of ArcGIS for Desktop?**

Generally, you can use a 10.1 or later version of ArcGIS for Desktop to publish a service to a 10.3.1 server. However, there are some restrictions to publishing if you are attempting to take advantage of functionality exclusive to 10.3.1:

If you're using web-tier authentication for your administrative connection, you must use 10.2 or later to publish.

If you're publishing to a server that is federated with Portal for ArcGIS, you must use 10.2 or later to publish.

If you're publishing a geoprocessing service, the ArcGIS for Desktop version must match ArcGIS for Server.

Comment: Oh wow! Much thanks. I guess my Googling skills aren't as sharp as I thought they were. Thanks for the prompt answer. You rock.